# Google Sheets - How to convert Average Page Load Time to seconds

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I'm retrieving data from the Google Analytics API into Google Sheets all the data looks perfect - except Average Page Load Time. Firstly, some of the values are displayed in the following format `HH.MM.SS` which seems wrong, while some others are displayed like `X.XXX` which seems correct.

I wonder how I "convert" the format `HH.MM.SS` into seconds, and also why do you think that this occurs?

(My locale is set to Swedish by the way.)

[image]

Comment: It is in `HH.MM.SS` format.

Comment: I don't believe `HH.MM.SS` format is the issue. From my brief testing, it seems like Sheets will sometimes interpret numbers as durations depending on the locale. I'm not sure how to fix this. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763906/paste-number-in-google-sheets-recognizing-the-proper-format/72765671#72765671